# jquery datatable export to excel- numbers in exponential notation

Tags: jquery, datatables, export-to-excel

I am using jquery datatable plugin to export data to excel and numbers greater than a specific length get converted to exponential notation. The closest solution I have found is converting the numbers to text.

```
 customizeData: function ( data ) {
         for (var i=0; i<data.body.length; i++){
             for (var j=0; j<data.body[i].length; j++ ){
                 data.body[i][j] = '\u200C' + data.body[i][j];
             }
         }
     },
```

This works but the the problem with this is that all my columns get converted to text form, which i dont want. Can I apply this code to one column only? or any other approach that I can take?

Comment: I don't believe there's anything you can do about this (other than convert the values to text) as Excel formats the numbers when displaying them.

Comment: Ok I will wokr my way around that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you help me with one other thing regarding datatables? In one of the columns i need to export a substring of the data, Can anything be done about that?